# Confusion in identifying independent events

Tags: probability

There are 6 white beads and 5 black beads in your pocket. You randomly pull the beads one by one out of your pocket and place them on a table. Probability that the third bead drawn is the first white.

Now the solution is : the prob.of drawning 1st black bead (5÷11) × the prob.of drawing 2nd black bead.(4÷10) × the prob.of drawing 1st white bead(6÷9) which equals to (4÷33) [By the product rule]
But isn't drawing the 1st black bead will affect the probability of drawing the 2nd black bead so the events are dependent?

I would be grateful if someone could clear my doubt
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1$ denote the event that the 1st bead drawn is black.

Let $E_2$ denote the event that the 2nd bead drawn is black.

Let $E_3$ denote the event that the 3rd bead drawn is white.

$E_1$ and $E_2$ are **definitely not independent** events.

However, the solution is somewhat poorly worded.  The solution might be better expressed as

$$p(E_1) \times p(E_2 | E_1) \times p(E_3 | E_1, E_2).\tag1 $$

The second factor above represents the chance of event $E_2$ occurring **given** that event $E_1$ occurred.

The third factor above represents the chance of event $E_3$ occuring **given** that events $E_1$ and $E_2$ both occurred.

The probabilities expressed in (1) above are consistent with the solution's math.  For example, once event $E_1$ occurs, then you have $(10)$ beads left, of which $(4)$ are black.